# GTK image установить размер отображения

Tags: c, linux, gtk

```
image = gtk_image_new_from_file ("картинка.jpg");
```

Как установить размер widget?
 К примеру 300 на 200, когда картинка сама имеет размер 1300 на 700

использую язык "си"!

Answer (score 1):

[GTK+ 3 Reference Manual: GtkWidget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html), однако.